# read a file and download the links in that file use urllib.request in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use urllib.request download a list links, and the links are in a file. For example, I have a file like this:

```
http://www.xxxxx.com/1.jpg
http://www.xxxxx.com/2.png
http://www.xxxxx.com/3.tar
http://www.xxxxx.com/4.zip
```

and many many more...

However, now I want to download them use urllib.request in python 3. I know how to read and download them:

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    for i in f.readlines()
        file = urllib.request.urlopen(i)
```

and then, I think I need open a file like `with open('file', 'wb') as f:`, but I don't know which file name should I use. Should I make a list and write some code like this: `with open(file_name_list, 'wb') as f:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close. If you want to name the files as they appear in the url, using a simple split with a [-1] will work pretty well. then you write out the response data to that file. EG.

```
file = urllib.request.urlopen(i)
filename = i.split('/')[-1]
with open(filename, 'wb') as out:
    out.write(file.read())
```

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: That is :) . But if there're two files and they have the same file name, then the last one will replace the first one. I know how to check and change the file name like`filename+'1'`. but if there're three file or four file have the same name, what should I do?

Comment: There are several things you could do, The most simple solution might be to just have an integer the you increase each line of the file and add it to the start of the filename. that way each file is unique. Otherwise you might want to hash the image url and use that as the filename. That way it should be unique majority of the time.

Comment: I understand, Thanks a lot :)